# Infinite Bernoulli Trials yielding the set of all infinite binary sequences of outcomes

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

As I learned it, a Bernoulli trial has exactly two possible outcomes (sometimes symbolized by $1$ or $0$), with each trial being probabilistically independent and each trial (or "experiment") having the same probability; and a sample space is the set of all possible outcomes; e.g. flipping a fair coin twice would yield a sample space of $\{HH, HT, TH, TT\}$.

The question: how to mathematically prove that an infinite sequence of Bernoulli trials yields a sample space of the set of all infinite binary sequences of outcomes?

It seems obvious to me that an infinite sequence of Bernoulli trials yields a sample space that is the set of all infinite binary sequences of outcomes (or "Cantor space" as I was taught), but I've interacted with some who doubt it. For sake of concreteness, I'll use the classic example of flipping a fair coin for the Bernoulli trial, such that infinitely many of these Bernoulli trials involves flipping a fair coin infinitely many times, and the apparent sample space would be every possible infinite sequence of heads/tails.

I thought of using mathematical induction to show this, but the response I got from using this was that it applies only to any finite number but not the whole set. For example, if I wanted to show that a sequence of all heads was part of the sample space via mathematical induction, at most I could prove this (where $H(x)$ means every flip less than or equal to the $x$th flip came up heads):

$ \forall x \lozenge H(x)$

And not this:

$\lozenge \forall x  H(x)$

As such, I don't know to mathematically prove that an infinite sequence of Bernoulli trials yields a sample space of the set of all infinite binary sequences of outcomes. How does one do it?

To quote from [this MIT open course link](https://ocw.mit.edu/high-school/mathematics/combinatorics-the-fine-art-of-counting/lecture-notes/MITHFH_lecturenotes_7.pdf):

> A Bernoulli process may be limited to a particular number of trials (e.g. 7 games, or 10 coin tosses), or it may go on indefinitely, in which case we may regard it as an infinite process. A finite Bernoulli sample space
> consists of all binary sequences of some particular length $n$ (1 denotes
> success, 0 failure). In the infinite case, the sample space consists of all infinite binary sequences.

The notion that, "In the infinite case, the sample space consists of all infinite binary sequences" is what I'm looking to prove.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Yes, you can make any binary sequence out of Bernoulli trials, though any particular sequence is generated with probability $0$.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I'm aware that any particular binary sequence out of Bernoulli trials has a probability of $0$. However, how to prove that you can make any binary sequence out of Bernoulli trials is kind of the the question. More specifically, how does one prove that an infinite sequence of Bernoulli trials yields a sample space of Cantor space?

Comment: What does that mean?  Usually, one speaks of the Cantor Space along with its topology.  As such it is homeomorphic to the standard Cantor set.  Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: As I learned it, set of all infinite binary sequences of outcomes is Cantor space. So to put it another way, how does one prove that an infinite sequence of Bernoulli trials yields a sample space of the set of all infinite binary sequences of outcomes?

Comment: The Cantor Space is a topological construction.  That's the point of it.  If all you mean is the underlying set, then where is the problem?  A sequence of trials is  a binary sequence of Successes and Fails.  A binary sequence is a sequence of $1's$ and $0's$.  So the bijection is achieved by mapping Successes to $1$ and Fails to $0$.

Comment: "If all you mean is the underlying set, then where is the problem?"

The problem is how to prove that an infinite sequence of Bernoulli trials yields a sample space of the set of all infinite binary sequences of outcomes. (I'm aware that $1$ can symbolize "success" and that $0$ can symbolize "fail.") For example, if each Bernoulli trial has a $0.5$ chance of success, and there are infinite trials, how to prove that the resulting sample space is the set of all infinite binary sequences of outcomes?

Comment: You just keep repeating the same words.  The underlying probabilities are not the issue since you aren't asking about the probability distribution.  I have written down the obvious bijection between a string of Bernoulli trials for *any* probability (well, other than $0$ or $1$).  Why does that explicit bijection not answer your question?

Comment: Perhaps this hypothetical will help. I claim that a binary sequence of $\{1, 1, 1, ...\}$ where 1 represents "Heads" is a possible outcome of flipping a fair coin infinitely many times. I say this is true because an infinite sequence of Bernoulli trials (binary outcome, probabilistically independent, each trial having the same probability) yields a sample space which is the set of all infinite binary sequences of outcomes, i.e. (in this case) every infinite binary sequence of outcomes is a possibility for this coin-flipping, but my interlocutor disagrees. How does one refute the interlocutor?

Comment: I don't see how you are distinguishing between an infinite sequence of Successes/Fails and an infinite sequence of 0's/1's.  It's just renaming things.  Similarly, the set of infinite sequences in $x's$ and $y's$ is also the set of binary sequences.  Probability has nothing to do with this, it's just names,

Comment: Closest I can come up with for a question here is:   "Show that attaching probabilities to infinite strings of standard Bernoulli trials in the obvious way induces the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, viewed as the collection of binary sequences.  "  At least that is connected to probability.  But, as I say, the question you actually wrote has no visible connection to probability.

Comment: "I don't see how you are distinguishing between an infinite sequence of Successes/Fails and an infinite sequence of 0's/1's."

I'm not.

I'll start over. As I learned it, a Bernoulli trial has exactly two possible outcomes (sometimes symbolized by $1$ or $0$), with each trial being probabilistically independent and each trial (or "experiment") having the same probability. How does one prove that after infinitely many Bernoulli trials, the set of all possible outcomes is the set of all infinite binary sequences?

Comment: I feel like we are going in circles, so I'll stop commenting.  Good luck.

Comment: Does the person you're talking to have any counter-proposal for what the sample space is?

Comment: A better question would be whether there is even a meaningful way to speak about whether a _single_ outcome in an uncountable sample space is "possible" or not. Well clearly, if the singleton event $\{x\}$ has positive probability measure, it must be "possible" -- but outside of that discrete case it's not clear to me that declaring a single outcome to be _impossible_ has any mathematical meaning that connects to the probability axioms.

Comment: I also do not understand the question.  What does "yields a sample space" mean?  Usually you start with a sample space, or you assume you have some sample space that supports your i.i.d. sequence. If Wade is trying to "prove" something, what, precisely, is the thing to be proven?

Comment: "Does the person you're talking to have any counter-proposal for what the sample space is?"

One person I talked to (I've talked to multiple people on this issue) believed the sample space included only those outcomes consisting of infinitely many heads and infinitely many tails. Yet it seems to me that the sample space of infinitely many Bernoulli trials would include all infinite binary sequences.

Comment: The sample space could be $S=\{red, blue\} \cup [0,1)$ and there indeed is a probability measure on that which could support an infinite sequence of i.i.d. Bernoulli trials.

Comment: _What does "yields a sample space" mean?_

I mean the sample space that would result from the trials in question; for example, flipping a fair coin twice would yield the sample space of $\{HH,HT,TH,TT\}$. It seems to me that the sample space for infinitely many Bernoulli trials is the set of all infinite binary sequences of outcomes; that's what I'd like to see proven.

Comment: I just told you the sample space could be $S = \{red, blue\} \cup [0,1)$, so I have provided a counter-example to your claim.  I am using sample space in the sense of a probability triplet $(S, \mathcal{F}, P)$. You can certainly construct other relevant sample spaces. You might be using "sample space" more informally.

Comment: @Michael

From [this link](https://ocw.mit.edu/high-school/mathematics/combinatorics-the-fine-art-of-counting/lecture-notes/MITHFH_lecturenotes_7.pdf):

"Bernoulli process may be limited to a particular number of trials (e.g. 7 games, or 10 coin-tosses), or it may go on indefinitely, in which case we may regard it as an infinite process. A finite Bernoulli sample space consists of all binary sequences of some particular length n (1 denotes success, 0 failure). In the infinite case, the sample space consists of all infinite binary sequences."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we define a sample space as the set of all possible outcomes, an infinite sequence of Bernoulli trials implies a sample space of the set of all infinite binary sequences of outcomes given a few assumptions.

For the Bernoulli process in question: each trial has exactly two possible outcomes, each trial is mutually independent (in the sense that the probability of the outcome is unaffected by the outcomes of other trials), and the probability is the same in each trial. Some additional assumptions to make the reasoning a bit easier to follow if nothing else: each candidate outcome for a trial (for example, heads or tails) has a nonzero probability, and any outcome with a nonzero probability is possible.

Let $\Omega$ represent the sample space of an infinite sequence of Bernoulli trials, which is the set of all possible outcomes for that sequence. For concreteness, let's symbolize the sequence of Bernoulli outcomes as $H$ and $T$ ("heads" and "tails," respectively) like so:

$(a_{i})^\infty_{i = 1}  \text{where } a_{i} \in \{H, T\}$

Since $H$ and $T$ both have nonzero probability for each trial, and nonzero probabilities entail possibility:

$\forall i \in \mathbb{N} \left [ \lozenge (a_{i} = H) \land \lozenge (a_{i} = T) \right ]$

Given the aforementioned conditions (e.g., both $H$ and $T$ have a nonzero probability), the fact that the probability of a given trial’s outcome is unaffected by the outcomes of other trials entails that *which outcomes are possible* for each trial is also unaffected by the outcomes of other trials. For each trial: (a) both outcomes are possible; and (b) which outcome is possible is unaffected by the outcomes of other trials. Since every element in the sequence has the property of heads or tails both being possible values regardless of the values of the other sequence elements, this permits any infinite sequence of binary values.

To illustrate, can the first coinflip be heads? Yes, since for each sequence element, $H$ or $T$ is a possible outcome, which would include the first coinflip. Given that the first coinflip is heads, can the second coinflip also be heads? Yes, since the possible outcomes of the second coinflip is unaffected by the outcomes of other coinflips; hence both $H$ and $T$ can be used here. If the first two coinflips are heads, can the third one be also? Yes, because the possible outcomes of the third coinflip is unaffected by the outcomes of the other coinflips, hence both $H$ and $T$ can be used here, and so on *ad infinitum* for all of the remaining sequence elements. And since the outcomes of heads is arbitrary here (e.g., we could just as well have used tails, heads, tails for the first three sequence elements, and then choose whatever binary sequence we wish for the remaining sequence elements) this can be generalized so that the sample space consists of all infinite binary sequences.

$\Omega = \left\lbrace  (a_{i})^\infty_{i = 1} \vert a_{i} \in \{H, T\} \right\rbrace$

Answer (score 0):

Let $(S, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability triplet: $S$ is the sample space, $\mathcal{F}$ is a sigma algebra on $S$ (containing all the events), and $P:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a probability measure.

Suppose $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of mutually independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) random elements. In particular
$$X_i:S\rightarrow \{H, T\}$$
is a measurable map from the sample space to the set $\{H,T\}$, so for each $i \in \{1, 2, 3,...\}$ we have
$$\{\omega \in S: X_i(\omega) = H\} \in \mathcal{F}$$
Assume $P[X_i=H]=P[X_i=T]=1/2$.

**Claim 1:** For each sequence $\{h_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ with $h_i \in \{H,T\}$, we have
$$\cap_{i=1}^{\infty} \{X_i=h_i\}= \cap_{i=1}^{\infty} \{\omega \in S: X_i(\omega)=h_i\} \in \mathcal{F}$$

Proof: Since $\mathcal{F}$ is a sigma algebra,  the countable intersection of events in $\mathcal{F}$ is in $\mathcal{F}$.  $\Box$

**Claim 2:** It is possible to construct $(S, \mathcal{F}, P)$, for which such i.i.d. random elements $\{X_i\}$ exist, in these example cases:

a) $S = \{red, blue\} \cup [0,1)$

b) $S = A$, where $A=\{(h_1, h_2, h_3, ...) : h_i \in \{H,T\}\quad \forall i \in \{1, 2, 3,...\}\}$.

c) $S =  A \setminus \{(T, T, T, T, ...)\}$.

In particular, examples (a) and (c) can be viewed as "counter-examples" to your claim that the sample space must contain all binary sequences of H/T.  The example (c) contains all binary sequences of H/T except for the all-Tails sequence $(T, T, T, T,...)$ (just start with the probability triplet in part (b) but throw away the probability-0 outcome of all tails).

---

Quick justifications for (a)-(c):

a) Use $P[\{red\}]=P[\{blue\}]=0$ and choose $\omega \in [0,1)$ according to the Borel sigma algebra and Borel measure.  Write $\omega\in [0,1)$ as
$$ \omega = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \omega_i 2^{-i}$$
where $\{\omega_i\}$ is the unique binary expansion that does not contain an infinite tail of 1s.  Define for each $i \in \{1,2,3,...\}$
$$X_i(red)=X_i(blue)=H$$
For $\omega \in [0,1)$ define
$$X_i(\omega) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
H & \mbox{if $\omega_i=1$}\\
T & \mbox{else} 
\end{array}\right.$$

b) This is the standard one.

c) Just start with (b) and throw away an outcome of probability 0.

Comment: For (c), I'm not prepared to think the MIT open course document was wrong quite yet. I'm wondering if there were implicit assumptions made for thinking that in the infinite case for Bernoulli trials, the sample space consists of all infinite binary sequences; e.g., some stronger notion of probabilistic independence (mutual independence as opposed to pairwise independence)?

Comment: The MIT notes are not wrong, they are just defining the most basic and reasonable sample space for learning. A part of learning basic probability is to work problems such as "construct a sample space to describe this experiment."  The sample space I use in part (c) is "unreasonable" in the sense that nobody would use it, it makes things more complicated to explain why I am allowed to throw away an outcome with probability 0 without affecting anything, yet it serves as a (counter-intuitive) counter-example that shows things can work even with unexpected sample spaces. [Here I use mutual ind.]

Comment: Even in the finite case, the probability space is only a model of a real-world experiment, albeit a rich and beautiful model in its own right, and one with very useful applications to real-world problems. As such, you are free to construct whatever probability space you like. One that's often used has as its sample space the set of all infinite binary sequences. Note that this set is uncountable, so it couldn't be produced by a sequence of experiments, even if the countably infinitely many trials in each experiment could be carried out in finite time, and even if the sequence of experiments...

Comment: ...was allowed to continue indefinitely.

Comment: @Michael While you can construct a sample space like you did in (c) I'm not sure just arbitrarily making a sample space like that fits the criteria; e.g. consider this sample space:

$S = \{HH,HT,TH\}$

While it's a valid sample space, it wouldn't be one that represents an i.i.d. of two Bernoulli trials since that would have included an outcome of $\{TT\}$. Similarly, the question was about a sample space in which an infinite sequence of i.i.d. Bernoulli trials are done (and more specifically mutually independent).

Comment: Instead of using the set of infinite binary sequences as your sample space, you could use the set of finite binary sequences of arbitrary length. In the former case, the sigma algebra can be the one generated by "cylinders".

Comment: @Wade : We can only throw away an outcome of probability zero. In your example you are throwing away the probability-1/4 outcome $TT$.   In my example of part (b), all outcomes have probability zero.  We can throw one away with impunity to create a new space $(\tilde{S}, \tilde{\mathcal{F}}, \tilde{P})$ that hardly changes. The event $\cap_{i=1}^{\infty} \{X_i=T\}$ is still a valid event in $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}$, but it is the event $\phi$ (the empty set) instead of the event $\{(T,T,T,T,...)\}$.

Comment: Throwing away the all-tails event is like conditioning on the probability-1 event $A$ that not all random elements are tails:  $$P[X_i=H|X_1, ..., X_{i-1},A] = P[X_i=H|X_1, ..., X_{i-1}]=1/2$$ In general, if $B$ and $A$ are events and $P[A]=1$ then $P[B \cap A] = P[B]$. Here is a formal link on throwing away events of probability zero: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4192299/intuitions-for-probability-on-countably-infinite-sample-spaces/4192797#4192797

Comment: @Simon : You cannot use a sample space of all finite binary sequences of arbitrary length, since that is a countably infinite sample space and is not big enough to support an infinite number of prob-1/2 i.i.d. random elements $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$. But you can indeed start with the sample space of all infinite binary sequences and generate a sigma algebra on that from the cylinder sets.

Comment: @Michael indeed, and thank you. In that case I meant (but failed to write) that the outcomes would necessarily be *finite* sequences of Bernoulli trials. Looking more carefully at the original question, I see that the OP did indeed specify that they wanted infinite sequences, so of course you are right that my comment was wrong. I also take your point that there's no way to *fix* (as in mend) that sample space by a clever mapping, since it isn't big enough.